# A proof in graph theory from an Olympiad - is my solution correct?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

**Question**: 90 people are in a room and each are acquainted with at least 60 others. Prove or disprove that at least four people have the same number of acquaintances.

**My solution**:
Represent the above as a graph and note that in the limiting case, the degree sequence of the graph (WLOG) is 60,60,60,61,61,61 ... 89,89,89. We cannot change any of these degrees as there are precisely 90 terms in the sequence with the restriction that $60 \leqslant deg(v_i) \leqslant 89$, where $v_i$ is any given contestant, and thus any change would create a group of 4.

By the fundamental theorem of graph theory, the sum of the degrees must be an even number by definition. Noting that there are 15 odd numbers in the range 60 to 89 inclusive (and that they are grouped in 3s), we can conclude that the sum is in fact odd and thus the construction of such a graph is impossible. This shows that there must be at least 4 people with the same number of acquaintances. $\square$

Comment: Sounds great.  Good use of handshaking lemma and pigeonhole.

Comment: My only gripe is that your argument is based on "making small adjustments to a best case scenario", and I'm not a fan of this solution approach (but I agree it's helpful as an initial heuristic). This raises the following concerns: 1/ You said that there is no way to change any of these degrees (just once - my interpretation) to get something else. But you've not shown that there is no way to change many of these degrees many times to get something else. 2/ You have not explicitly proven that there are no other limiting cases to consider.